# R Shiny : How to use parameters from a tagList() to run a function?

Tags: shiny

I need some help to use 2 parameters which are obtained with a tagList() to run a function, but I don't find how to do that.
I use the dataframe df_all to suggest to the user what parameters he can choose. (for example, all years are not available with all "varietes")

I have :

```
varietes <- list("First letter" = "A",
                 "Second letter" = "B",
                 "Third letter" = "C")

df_all = data.frame(ID = c(1:6),
                    YEAR = c(rep(2012,3), rep(2015,3)),
                    TYPE = c("T1", "T2", "T1", "T3", "T2", "T1"))
```

in the UI.R I use :

```
selectInput(inputId = "cult", 
            choices = varietes,
            selected = "A"),
uiOutput("ui")
```

And in the server.R I use :

```
  output$ui <- renderUI({
    tagList(
      checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "annee", choices = df_all %>% filter(year == input$cult) %>% select(YEAR) %>% distinct() %>% pull()),
      checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "type", choices = df_all %>% filter(type == input$cult) %>% select(TYPE) %>% distinct() %>% pull())
    )
```

I tried :

```
  output$ui <- renderUI({
    tagList(
      ye <- checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "annee", choices = df_all %>% filter(year == input$cult) %>% select(YEAR) %>% distinct() %>% pull()),
      ty <- checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "type", choices = df_all %>% filter(type == input$cult) %>% select(TYPE) %>% distinct() %>% pull())
     )

myfunction(arg1 = ye, arg2 = ty)
```

but you can imagine it didn't work

I want to execute a function with the parameters chosen in the tagList() but I don't find how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the key answer here is you refer to inputs created via `renderUI` just like you would if you are defining them in the UI directly

```
myFunction(arg1 = input$annee, arg2 = input$type)
```

That being said, I think there may be a few other issues with your filtering. In the future, please provide a full [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) along with your question. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for a discussion on the topic as well.

For example, here is a potential more full code example so others could more quickly test their answers to your question

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

varieties <- LETTERS[1:3]
df_all <- data.frame(
  cult = rep(varieties, 2),
  year = 1990:1995,
  type = c("aires", "gemini", "cancer", "leo", "scorpio", "virgo")
)

myFunction <- function(arg1, arg2){
  sprintf("Year: %s, Type: %s", arg1, arg2)
}

ui <- fluidPage(

  selectInput(inputId = "cult", 
              label = h3("Culture"),
              choices = varieties,
              selected = "A"),
  uiOutput("ui"),
  textOutput("myResult")

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$ui <- renderUI({

    tagList(
      checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "annee", label = h3("YEAR"), 
                         choices = df_all %>% 
                           filter(year == input$cult) %>% 
                           select(YEAR) %>% 
                           distinct() %>% 
                           pull()),
      checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "type", label = h3("TYPE"), 
                         choices = df_all %>% 
                           filter(type == input$cult) %>% 
                           select(TYPE) %>% 
                           distinct() %>% 
                           pull())
    )
  })

  output$myResult <- renderText({
    myFunction(arg1 = input$annee, arg2 = input$type)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Make sure to include minimal sample data and when possible your expected outcome.